# Eclipse does not recognizing classes

Tags: eclipse, class

Is it true that eclipse at times does not recognize classes imported in its project library? I was facing a similar problem and tried to do some research on it and came across a few instances of this. Have you ever faced this issue? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe exactly what "does not recognise" means. Also, provide any links you found in your research.

Comment: Hi Arkadiy, thanks for the response.  Here is one link. 'http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/373752-noclassdeffounderror/'.

Comment: What I meant was despite importing all necessary jars, it still gives a NoClassDefFoundError. Here is a link to a url of an image showing my problem. http://tinypic.com/r/o5ch0n/8

Comment: You're being helped at dreamincode.net. Keep working with them.